# Removing an index from an alias in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How can we remove an index from an alias? That is, I no longer need to associate an index to an alias.

My second question is - can an alias exist without any indexes?

Answer (score 27):

In case you don't know the name of index and you want to remove alias from all indexes

```
Post: /_aliases
{
 "actions" : [
    { "remove" : { "index" : "*", "alias" : "nameOfAlias" } }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Add an alias:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": ".marvel-2015.06.05",
        "alias": "alias1"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": ".marvel-2015.06.04",
        "alias": "alias1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

List the alias:

```
GET /alias1/_alias
```

Remove one index:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "remove": {
        "index": ".marvel-2015.06.05",
        "alias": "alias1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And "no", an alias cannot exists without indices: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7864

Answer (score 3):

You can run following in elasticsearch dev tools console

```
DELETE /<your_index>/_alias/<unwanted_alias_to_be_removed>
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.